# Is $f(z)=\frac{|z|^{3/2}e^{i3\arg(z)}-1}{|z|e^{2i\arg(z)}-1}$ bounded for $|z|\in (0,1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f:B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ denote the function defined by
$$f(z)=\dfrac{|z|^{3/2}e^{3i\arg(z)}-1}{|z|e^{2i\arg(z)}-1}.$$
Is f bounded above on $B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$? I believe it should be, but I cannot seem to show this. It can be seen that such a function has the following form:
$$
f(z)
 = \frac{|z|^3e^{6i\arg(z)}-1}{|z|e^{2i\arg(z)}-1}
   \cdot \frac{|z|^{3/2}e^{3i\arg(z)}-1}{\left(|z|^{3/2}e^{3i\arg(z)}\right)^2-1}
 = \frac{1+|z|e^{2i\arg(z)}+|z|^2e^{4i\arg(z)}}{1+|z|^{3/2}e^{3i\arg(z)}},
$$
but I cannot see where this would help. Any hints would be much appreciated. Here when considering balls and boundedness we are considering the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Pick $z=-r, \arg z=\pi$; then $f(-r)=\frac {r^{3/2}+1}{1-r} \to \infty, r \to 1$

Comment: Yes thank you for that. Feel free to post a complete answer and I will accept.

Comment: no problem - done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we choose $z=-r, 0<r<1$ we have that $\arg z =\pi$ so $f(z)=f(-r)=\frac {r^{3/2}+1}{1-r}$

But as $r \to 1$ the expression above goes to $+\infty$ so indeed $f$ is superior unbounded

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. To see why, we'll  simplify the notations: set $\sqrt{|z|}=r\enspace(0<r<1)$, $u=\mathrm e^{i\arg z}$. Then
$$f(z)=\frac{r^3u^{3}-1}{r^2u^2-1}= \frac{r^2u^2+ru+1}{ru+1}$$
and we see that  $\;|r^2u^2+ru+1| \le |r|^2+|r|+1 < 3$, whereas $ru +1\longrightarrow 0$, when $r\longrightarrow 1\:$ and $\:\arg z\longrightarrow \pi$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I meant $u=\mathrm e^{i\arg z}$. I'll fix it within seconds.